# Why isn't this printing to the console in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, io

Given this code, I am baffled as to why it doesn't print to the console....

```
    engine.compileTemplate(new PrintWriter(System.err));
    System.err.flush();
```

I see nothing on the console. Same problem with System.out too. And yes I verified that the code works by printing to a file successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [constructor with autoflush](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.io.OutputStream,%20boolean%29). You are flushing System.err, not the PrintWriter.

Comment: Yes, but then you should flush the PrintWriter, not the System.err?

Answer (score 0):

In what context is this code executed?
Really need more info to determine what's going on.

Is your code running in a plugin that you are debugging?
If so, then with "print to the console" - do you mean the console of the same Eclipse instance as your plugin?

For that you would need to do something like:

```
MessageConsole console = new MessageConsole("My Console", null);
console.activate();
ConsolePlugin.getDefault().getConsoleManager().addConsoles(new IConsole[]{ console });
MessageConsoleStream consoleStream = console.newMessageStream();
consoleStream.println("Hello, world!");
```

Otherwise, it goes to the console where Eclipse was launched.

Read more here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_write_to_the_console_from_a_plug-in%3F